# Images appear discoloured in Image Viewer

Tags: 14.04, eog

Every image I open using Image Viewer is discoloured. It appears more green-ish and purple-ish. I am using Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS.

EOG image on the left, Firefox on the right:

[image: image comparison]

How can I solve this?